# I am trying to add two arrays with any given numbers to a new array. get an error when carrying a number

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static int[] sum(int[] firstNumber,int[] secondNumber) {

    int[] sum= new int[firstNumber.length >= secondNumber.length ? firstNumber.length+1 : secondNumber.length+1];


    for (int i = 0; i < firstNumber.length; ++i) {
        sum[i] = firstNumber[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i< secondNumber.length;i++) {
        if((sum[i]+secondNumber[i])>9)
        {
        sum[i] += (secondNumber[i]-10);
        sum[i-1]+=1;
        }
        else
        {
        sum[i]+=secondNumber[i];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

when I add 9+1 or any combination like it that requires carrying a 1, I get an error.

Comment: Just curious, why are you making the sum[] the size of one larger than the maximum size?

Comment: to hold the number that carries over. so say it was 9 plus 1. i want to carry the 1 over to sum[0] and have the 0 at sum[1]

Comment: Does `sum[0]` hold the most significant digit or the least significant digit?  Eg, is the number 134 stored as `{1,3,4}` or `{4,3,1}`?

Answer (score 0):

`sum[i-1]+=1;` will cause an exception when `i` is 0, since the index of an array can't be negative.

Comment: thanks man. I still havent figured out how to carry the number. Been working on this for hours....

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int[] sum(int[] firstNumber,int[] secondNumber) {    
    int[] sum= new int[firstNumber.length >= secondNumber.length ? firstNumber.length : secondNumber.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < (firstNumber.length >= secondNumber.length ? firstNumber.length : secondNumber.length); ++i) {
      sum[i] += firstNumber.length >= secondNumber.length ? firstNumber[i] : secondNumber[i];
    }

    for (int i = (firstNumber.length >= secondNumber.length ? s econdNumber.length : firstNumber.length)-1; i>=0;i--) {
      if((sum[i]+(firstNumber.length >= secondNumber.length ?  secondNumber[i] : firstNumber[i]))>9)
      {
        if(i==0){
        sum[0]=(firstNumber.length >= secondNumber.length ? secondNumber[i] : firstNumber[i])+sum[0];
        sum[1]+=(sum[1]+(firstNumber.length >= secondNumber.length ? secondNumber[i] : firstNumber[i]))-10;
      }      
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

I changed some things up so that I can figure out which length is longer. I still haven't figured out how to carry the numbers.

Comment: Edit this into your question, don't add it as another answer.